# Is it viable/thread-safe to use a static HttpClient in a using block?

Tags: c#, static, dotnet-httpclient, using

Say I have a controller with an `Index()` method, and this controller utilizes multiple "Manager classes" that manage certain assets that need to be retrieved with an `HttpClient` from an API.

I've read that sharing an `HttpClient` with multiple calls is better than to reinstantiate it with every call to save ports.

I do however want to dispose of the `HttpClient` before the controller returns the view, because the view contains an entire Knockout/Typescript based front end project that handles the rest of the data (so it's basically only settings and meta data stuff).

Do I need to pass the `HttpClient` variable to each and every "Manager class", or does it suffice to do something like the following, and use a static `HttpClient` inside the classes?

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
  using (Globals.Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
  {
    // do stuff like SettingManager.GetSetting("settingKey") which uses 
    // the Globals.Client variable
  }
  return View();
}
```

Or should I not even want to dispose the `HttpClient` in the first place?

Comment: Don't do that, you will likely get an object disposed exception when another request is in-flight. You do not need to dispose it, it doesn't matter what the view contains.

Comment: @Crowcoder Won't the connections fill up with TCP ESTABLISHED that don't disappear until they time out? I've got quite a load so this could be a problem.

Comment: If you're creating something and disposing it within a method then it should be declared within that method. But we also shouldn't create/dispose `HttpClient`. We should create a single instance and re-use it. It's counter-intuitive because `IDisposable` means we dispose when we're done with it. But if we re-use it then we're never done with it.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the specifics at that level, but I know that it will re-use connections which saves from establishing handshakes every time and prevents socket exhaustion.

Comment: @ScottHannen I've tried that before, but it seems to disconnect after being inactive for some time. I'll dive into trying to prevent that.

Comment: One suggestion is to define some abstraction (interface) that describes what you're using the `HttpClient` for, and inject that into your controller. The implementation of that class uses `HttpClient`. You can register it with DI as a singleton, and that class maintains a single instance of `HttpClient`. That kills three birds with one stone: Each individual controller isn't responsible for maintaining the lifetime of the client, there's no "global" client, and the controllers don't depend directly on `HttpClient` so they're more testable.

Comment: Disconnection is not a problem for HTTP protocol - it's regular thing. Normal HTTP communication implies establishing connection, sending request, receiving response and then disconnection unless client and server use keep-alive header to reuse the connection for another interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to make a separate dependency responsible for managing your `HttpClient`. This has the side benefit of keeping your controllers from depending directly on `HttpClient`. Any class that depends on `HttpClient` becomes harder to test. It's also a maintenance issue because if you want to change the behavior you have to change it everywhere. Imagine if you decide one day that whatever you're getting from that `HttpClient` can be cached? You'd have to change it in lots of classes.

You can define an abstraction and implementation like this:

```
public interface IDoesSomething
{
    string GetSetting(string key);
}

public class HttpClientDoesSomething : IDoesSomething, IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly string _apiUrl;

    public HttpClientDoesSomething(string apiUrl)
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _apiUrl = apiUrl;
    }

    public string GetSetting(string key)
    {
        // use the client to retrieve the setting
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _client?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is moved out of your controller because you inject the interface:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDoesSomething _doesSomething;

    public MyController(IDoesSomething doesSomething)
    {
        _doesSomething = doesSomething;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var setting = _doesSomething.GetSetting("whatever"); 
        // whatever else this does.
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now in your startup configuration you can register `HttpClientDoesSomething` as a singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<IDoesSomething>(new HttpClientDoesSomething("url from settings"));
```

Your implementation is disposable, so if you do need to create and dispose it you will also dispose the `HttpClient`. But it won't be an issue because your application will keep reusing the same one.